# Question about epsilon neighborhoods

Tags: analysis, epsilon-delta

I do not know how I am supposed to solve the following question.

> Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ be such that $a > b − \epsilon$  for all $\epsilon > 0.$ Prove that $a \geq b.$

Comment: Suppose that $a < b$ and show that this results in a contradiction. Hint: if $a < b$ then choose some $\epsilon$ satisfying $0 < \epsilon < b-a$.

Comment: @Bungo then how would you go from there?